# ActivityView not showing

Tags: ios, hidden, progress, uiactivityindicatorview

I am trying to add a download progress view to my app, and while it shows in the debug preview, it does not actually show on the device. Can anyone explain this to me?

Here is a screenshot of the debug and some code:

[image]

```
- (void)updateDownloadProgressWithBatchIndex:(int)index contentName:(NSString *)name
{
    CGSize size = self.view.bounds.size;

    _loadingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 155, 170, 170)];
    _loadingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    _loadingView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    _loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
    [_loadingView setCenter:CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2)];

    _activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    _activityView.frame = CGRectMake(65, 40, _activityView.bounds.size.width,     _activityView.bounds.size.height);
    _activityView.hidden = NO;
    [_activityView setCenter:CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2)];
    [_loadingView addSubview:_activityView];

    _loadingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 115, 130, 22)];
    _loadingLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _loadingLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _loadingLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    _loadingLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    _loadingLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Batch %i downloading...", index];
    [_loadingView addSubview:_loadingLabel];

    [self.view addSubview:_loadingView];
    _loadingView.hidden = NO;
    UIView *v = self.view;
    [_activityView startAnimating];
}
```

Comment: How is `updateDownloadProgressWithBatchIndex` being _called_?

Comment: It it being called from a method within the same class when the download starts, and that class is a view controller.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. I'm asking you to _show the code_. If that method goes on to do more work, the activity view might never have a chance to appear. Isn't that what you're trying to figure out?

Comment: I see what you are asking now. Just a sec

Comment: Also, what is the "debug preview" in your question? Do you mean the Simulator? Or what?

Comment: I mean when I hover over the 'v' variable and click on the eye icon. It shows a preview of the view. I am using widevine and don't have it set up to work in the sim. Also, I have looked through the rest of that method that calls the updateDownloadProgress method, and there isn't anything that effects the UI. I would post it, but it is rather large, and uses a lot of proprietary code.

Comment: Well, I didn't ask whether it affects the UI. What I said was, and still say: if you call `updateDownloadProgress` but then proceed to do more stuff, you are preventing the activity view from spinning. The activity view cannot spin until _your code stops_. - I have a sneaky suspicion that you are also going to do synchronous networking, which is (a) wrong and (b) time-consuming and would certainly cause the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a wild guess - it has to be wild, because you refuse to show your code - that you are proceeding to synchronous networking after you call `updateDownloadProgress`. That's the cause of the issue. The inability of the activity view to start spinning would thus be diagnostic, the *real* issue being the synchronous networking, which is a no-no.

Comment: Sorry for all of the misunderstandings. I think what have said has triggered some ideas. Thank you for your help.